# JSP - How can I combine filters and pagination?

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm developing an application with Spring and I'm stuck trying to combine filters and pagination in my page.

Independently, my filters and my pagination are working fine, I'm able to change pages and filter my list of teams.

My problem occurs when I apply a filter and then try to change the page. My filter automatically resets.

Is there a way to keep the `form` information when I click an `href` link?

I also tried to add a "submit button" for each page number, but with no sucess.

What is the best way to achieve this solution?

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>List of teams</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/lista.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of teams</h1>
        <p>Here you can see the list of the teams, edit them, remove or update.</p>

        <form:form method="POST" action="/SpringMVCTeams/team/list">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Country</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="country">
                            <form:option value="default-value" label="--Please Select" />
                            <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="idCountry" itemLabel="name" />
                        </form:select>          
                    </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="country" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Division</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="division">
                            <form:option value="default-value" label="--Please Select" />
                            <form:options items="${divisionList}" itemValue="idDivision" itemLabel="name" />
                        </form:select>          
                    </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="division" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>     
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <c:forEach begin="1" end="${paginationProducts}" var="p">
                <a href="/SpringMVCTeams/team/list/${p}">${p}</a>
            </c:forEach>


        </form:form>

        <table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">id</th>
                    <th width="15%">name</th>
                    <th width="10%">rating</th>
                    <th width="10%">actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="team" items="${teams}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${team.id}</td>
                    <td>${team.name}</td>
                    <td>${team.rating}</td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/edit/${team.id}.html">Edit</a><br/>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/delete/${team.id}.html">Delete</a><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html">Home page</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.

I added buttons to submit with different `value` information. Then, in the controller, I verified the value of the parameter `action`.

**JSP Page:**

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="/SpringMVCTeams/team/list">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Country</label></td>
                    <td>
                    <form:select path="country">
                        <form:option value="default-value" label="--Please Select" />
                        <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="idCountry" itemLabel="name" />
                    </form:select>          
                </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="country" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Division</label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="division">
                        <form:option value="default-value" label="--Please Select" />
                        <form:options items="${divisionList}" itemValue="idDivision" itemLabel="name" />
                    </form:select>          
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="division" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>     
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="1" class="btn-link">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${paginationProducts}" var="p">
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="${p}" class="btn-link">${p}</button>
            </c:forEach>

    </form:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/list" , method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView listOfTeams(HttpServletRequest request, TeamList teamList) {
    String action= request.getParameter("action");

    if(action == null)
        return getlistOfTeams(teamList, 1);
    else
        return getlistOfTeams(teamList, Integer.parseInt(action));
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better solution?